# R.id.viewpager crashes after android SDK update

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

i'm about to do some updates with my android app i've not seen for a while (almost a year). now, when i've updated SDK, my app crashes.

i deleted `SherlockActionBar` and switched totally to an android support library (v7.appcompat) and now i have an issue i don't actually understand, because it wasn't a part of fixes i made today.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

the line above tells me that 'viewpager' symbol cannot be resolved. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

See if module dependcies are correctly set up, and rebuild the project..

(or just turn the studio on and off)

is their

is the dependencies correctly set up in build.gradle?

and a jar file in your lib folder?